# How can I animate list items to be apeared one by one with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css-animations, listitem

I need to animate (fade in) following list items to be appeared one by one by one. As the [right side drawer in this website](http://europejski.pl/home).

```
<ul>
    <li class="fade-item">Item 01</li>
    <li class="fade-item">Item 02</li>
    <li class="fade-item">Item 03</li>
    <li class="fade-item">Item 04</li>
    <li class="fade-item">Item 05</li>
</ul>
```

This is the JavaScript code.

```
function fadeItems() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("fade-item");

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            items[i].classList.add("fadein");
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Css styles are here.

```
.fade-item {
    transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-item .fadein {
    animation: fadeIn 0.9s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

When the function is executed it gives following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

I need this to code using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

because when you use `setTimeout(handler, delay)`, the handler was called in other context.

If you want to **fade in items one by one**, you should use different delay for each item.

If you want to **fade in items** after you add class `fadein`, your css should be

```
.fade-item {
    transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

.fadein {
    animation: fadeIn 0.9s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/dkojpcpt/

Answer (score 0):

`items[i].className="fade-item fadeIn"`
There is a space between the classes.